# Could not load component class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener error occurs in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-batch, spring-integration

when i try to execute spring mvc application i am facing below issue.

```
 my controller class:-

package com.prasad.spring;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld(){
        String message = "HELLO SPRING MVC HOW R U";  
        return new ModelAndView("hellopage", "message", message);

    }
}
```

and below welcome jsp file under WebContent folder

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring MVC Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="hello.html">click Here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

below web.xml file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SpringMVCFirst</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
   <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
   <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

below spring-servlet.xml from Webconte/WEB-INF folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd


http://www.springframework.org/schema/context


http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="net.viralpatel.spring3.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

below jsp file from /WEB-INF/jsp/

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Message is: ${message}  
</body>
</html>
```

when i run above code on JBOSS7 i am facing below issue

```
23:57:49,379 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."SpringMVCFirst.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."SpringMVCFirst.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "SpringMVCFirst.war"

23:57:49,383 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"SpringMVCFirst.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"SpringMVCFirst.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"SpringMVCFirst.war\""}}}}
00:06:49,803 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found SpringMVCFirst.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called SpringMVCFirst.war.dodeploy
00:06:49,814 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "SpringMVCFirst.war"
00:06:49,842 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."SpringMVCFirst.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."SpringMVCFirst.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "SpringMVCFirst.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011093: Could not load component class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:113)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener from [Module "deployment.SpringMVCFirst.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:111)
    ... 7 more
```

and also i have added all spring jar files. please any one help to me where my code getting error

thanks in advance

Comment: Share, please, an info where is the Spring jars, especially `spring-web`

Comment: hello artem,above specified issue has been resolved by jars but right now facing different issue  is   "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCFirst/hello.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'" please help me

Comment: Show, please, full url from the client. And pay attention that you have a mapping for `/hello`, but not for `/hello*`. And what is worse, not for `/SpringMVCFirst`

Answer (score 0):

how about adding
`<param-value>classpath:/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>`. Try above one by adding classpath to param-value. So ContextLoaderListener can find your spring-servlet file.